# LibGdx resolutionFileResolver + Assetmanager, file names?

Tags: android, libgdx, resolution, assets, texture-atlas

I want to use the resolution file resolver to select a correct texture atlas for my app, so I createa RFR with a couple of resolutions:

```
Resolution _568x1136 = new Resolution(568, 1136, ".568x1136");
Resolution _1200x1920 = new Resolution(568, 1136, ".1200x1920");
ResolutionFileResolver resolver = new ResolutionFileResolver(new InternalFileHandleResolver(), _568x1136, _1200x1920);

manager = new AssetManager();
manager.setLoader(TextureAtlas.class, new TextureAtlasLoader(resolver));
```

Now I'm wondering, how do I name/place the files??????

I tried adding .1200x1920 and .568x1136 behind BOTH the .png and the .atlas (.png.568.1136, etc), but that didn't work.

I also tried using folders (parent/568x1136/file.atlas).

I try to load the atlas in the following manner:

```
manager.load("data/atlas/splashscreen/splashscreen.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);                     // First make sure the splash screen
manager.finishLoading();                                                                            // is loaded before loading anything
Assets.splashAtlas = manager.get("data/atlas/splashscreen/splashscreen.atlas", TextureAtlas.class); // else
```

Comment: I don't actually see where you are using the resolver.

Comment: Added it in the code, forgot tot copy it.

Comment: Try removing the **.** from the suffix and try putting the file to `data/atlas/splashscreen/568x1136/splashscreen.atlas`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// no dots were used for the "suffix"
Resolution _568x1136 = new Resolution(568, 1136, "568x1136");
Resolution _1200x1920 = new Resolution(568, 1136, "1200x1920");
ResolutionFileResolver resolver = new ResolutionFileResolver(new InternalFileHandleResolver(), _568x1136, _1200x1920);

manager.load("data/atlas/splashscreen/splashscreen.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);                     
manager.finishLoading();                                                                      
Assets.splashAtlas = manager.get("data/atlas/splashscreen/splashscreen.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
```

Despite other answers on stackoverflow regarding the `ResolutionFileResolver`, it actually *does* make use of a folder hierarchy to retrieve the correct images. If we assume that `568x1136` would be the best matching resolution, it will search for `data/atlas/splashscreen/568x1136/splashscreen.atlas` now. If this file cannot be found, the fallback will be just `data/atlas/splashscreen/splashscreen.atlas`. If this file also doesn't exist, an exception will occur.

So the name "suffix" is not really correct anymore. The implementation seems to have changed over time. The "suffix" is not being appended to the files anymore.

Comment: You sir are a true hero :)